# update function returned by useState hook not updating the value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Something very weird is going on. I have a state value which is defined as follows:

```
const [heightField, setHeightField] = useState<FormField<string>>(new FormField<string>(""));
```

I have also defined a useEffect hook which is tied to this state value, it is defined as follows:

```
useEffect(() => console.log('heightfield changed, hi from the useEffect hook!'), [heightField]);
```

This heightField value is referenced in a text field as follows:

```
      <TextField
    required
    label="Height (cms)"
    margin="normal"
    variant="outlined"
    type="number"
    value={heightField.value}
    onChange={(event) => {
      setHeightField(new FormField<string>(event.target.value))
    }}
    error={heightField.error}
    helperText={heightField.errorMessage}
  />
```

Now, when I input text in the textfield, the heightField value is updated accordingly and the useEffect hook is triggered as well.

However, when updating the heightField value from another function, its value is not updated nor is the useEffect hook triggered. Frankly I do not understand why this behavior is happening. The function is the following:

```
const validateHeight = (heightField: FormField<string>) => {

    const heightNumber = parseInt(heightField.value);
    let error = false;
    let errorMessage = "";
    if (!heightNumber) {
      error = true;
      errorMessage = "Wrong number, please verify.";
    }
    else if (heightNumber < 0 || heightNumber > 220) {
      error = true;
      errorMessage = "Please verify the height";
    }
    const nHeightField = new FormField<string>(heightField.value, error, errorMessage);
    setHeightField(nHeightField);
  }
```

This function is called when hitting the submit button of a form and when invoked, the useEffect hook is not triggered and neither is the heightField value updated accordingly

Is there something I am missing? why isn't this value being updated when invoking the update function with a new object?

Comment: My guess is that somehow the value of `heightField` is actually the same between renders, even after validating height. `const nHeightField = new FormField<string>(heightField.value, error, errorMessage);` looks suspicious to me. Is this a custom class you've written? What is the value of `nHeightField` immediately after this line?

Comment: Yes, FormField is a custom class I have created. The objects are different after executing the validateHeightField function, I am typing incorrect values so the error property is true and there is an error message. heightField before the update: Object { value: "3434343434", error: false, errorMessage: "" }
and nHeightField is: 
Object { value: "3434343434", error: true, errorMessage: "Please verify the height" }

Answer (score 2):

From what you've told us in your question and comments, it seems that the `state` object reference is remaining the same, even though its properties have changed. Try to create a copy of that object by doing something like the following:

```
setState({...heightField});
```

Or if you need something from the previous `state` before updating it:

```
setState((prevState) => {
 const aux = {...prevState};
 aux.someProp = someOtherValue;
 return aux;
});
```

If your state is an object, and the object reference remains the same in between renders, React will think it hasn't changed and won't update it. Because it only compares the value. If it's a `number` or a `string` it will compare by value, but if it's an `object` it will compare by reference and will not dive into the `object` properties.

Comment: I will give it a try! However, given that I am creating a new object, shouldn't the reference be different?

Comment: Where is the `validateHeight` function getting the object from? Is it coming from the state? Because if it is, you're getting the same reference and returning the same reference.

Comment: If you spread its props like I did on the `aux` example you create a new object, thus with different reference. Try to return something  that.

Comment: The object comes from the state indeed. However, I am creating a new object where the error and errorMessage values are different from the one I am getting by parameters. I am also creating a new object which only has the string fieldValue in common, the rest is different. The object is created and set in lines ```const nHeightField = new FormField<string>(heightField.value, error, errorMessage);
    setHeightField(nHeightField);```

Comment: spreading the props does not make much sense since I am only using the string value of the object, the other properties are discarded. However, I will give it a try as soon as I get home.

Comment: Alright. When the state is not triggering a re-render it's usually because the reference is not changing. Let me know how it goes. You can share the FormField code too. That might help to understand the source of the problem.